# How to obtain data that is in at least one table of several related in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with a problem I have about SQL.

I have three tables, Table1, Table2, Table3 all with an "email" field with which they relate to each other.

On the other hand, I have an array with a list of emails that I have to check if they are in one of those tables. These emails also have them saved in a string separated with commas and with their respective quotes to use it in an IN (....):

```
$emails = ("'email1@example.com', 'email2@example.com', ....");

SELECT * 
FROM Table t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.email = t2.email 
INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.email = t3.email 
WHERE (t1.email IN ($ emails)) OR (t2.email IN ($ emails) ) OR (t3.email IN ($ emails));
```

With the previous example, I realized that when doing an INNER JOIN I was matching the tables by the email field which did not have the value in all the tables. It may be the case that an email is not in some table but in another yes, so I need an SQL query so that I get the emails that are in ANY of the 3 tables.

I have been told that I made a temporary table of the emails array and then doing LEFT JOIN between the tables I could get it, but I do not know how to do it.

Could you give me an idea of ​​how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If t2 has 100 rows with the same email, and t3 has 100 rows with the same email, you will get at least 10,000 rows in your result.

Comment: Exactly, but I forgot to comment that I wanted to group it by email, to get only one row by email.

Comment: but which row? Without careful grouping and aggregation, you'd just be getting random data associated with the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `UNION`, not `JOIN`.

```
SELECT email, "Table1" AS whichTable
FROM Table1
WHERE email in ($email)
UNION
SELECT email, "Table2" AS whichTable
FROM Table2
WHERE email in ($email)
UNION
SELECT email, "Table3" AS whichTable
FROM Table3
WHERE email in ($email)
```

Using `SELECT *` in all the queries assumes that all the tables have similar columns in the same order. If not, you'll need to list the columns explicitly in each query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Barmar, is there no other way than with UNION? I commented to you, I need to use a php function that handles the connection to the database and it passes three parameters that are the SELECT, FROM and WHERE (with GRUOP BY, ORDER BY, ...) to perform the query, so I do not see how to use UNION there.

Comment: Nope, sorry.  Sounds like you need to make that function more flexible, or bypass it with a real query.

Comment: You could call it separately for each table, and then combine the results in PHP.

Comment: With regard to SELECT *, I just need to get the email, but when I do not know which table it may be in, I do not know which table to use: t1.email, t2.email or t3.email?

Comment: So use `SELECT email` instead of `SELECT *`.

Comment: Do you need to know which table it was found in?

Comment: I've shown how to add that as another column in the result.

Comment: Not at the moment, only the emails that are in one of those tables. I will try what you have told me to see if I get it. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170114/discussion-between-joseph-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward way that should return a single Boolean value.  `EXISTS` is useful because it (should) ignore looking at any additional rows as soon as it finds one.

```
SELECT 
   EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE email IN (...))
   OR
   EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE email IN (...))
   OR
   EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE email IN (...))
```